# How to set height to grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

This is my grid view

```
<div class="gridView">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="MembershipID"
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
```

THe result of that code is the grid view shows 5 rows and the paging is under the fifth row.

#### my problem

the pager is not shows so I have to scroll to show it.

#### my quesiton

how can I make the pager shows without using scroll?

#### Edit

this is the css

```
.gridView
{
    max-height: 280px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.gridView th
{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on you need to scroll? May be post an image as well. Also I an not sure if there's any other UI causing issue due to a div inside your GV.

Comment: @gbs I added the image

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is your "gridview" css class  trying to make the gridview scrollable?

Comment: @gbs the `AllowScrolling` exist in the code that I provided, and I will edit the question to give you the css

Comment: You meant AllowSorting? I think it is the max-height and overflow. Try commenting that out and see if that helps.

Comment: @gbs you great, it works :) :) :) thanks a lot a lot a lot. write an answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max-height and overflow in the "gridview" class is causing the scroll-bar to appear.
Remove those properties.

Comment: I apprecitae your help. I still have another question, tomorrow, I will write it and told you about it. thanks a lot. you great